# OnUpdateMenuUI in C#?

Tags: c#, menu

Is there any mechanism where I can get update notification when users try to open an menu item, like in MFC.
I know there is no direct way, but there should be lot of hacks, that's what I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What architecture?

In winforms (`MenuStrip`) you can use the `DropDownOpening` event - that do?

On the older `MenuItem`, there is the `Popup` event that works similarly.

I'm not sure about WPF...

This demonstrates both (`MenuItem` first, then `ToolStripMenuItem`):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
static class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        // older menuitem
        MenuItem mi;
        using (Form form = new Form {
            Menu = new MainMenu {
                MenuItems = {
                    (mi = new MenuItem("abc"))
                }
            }
        })
        {
            mi.MenuItems.Add("dummy");
            mi.Popup += delegate {
                mi.MenuItems.Clear();
                mi.MenuItems.Add(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            };
            Application.Run(form);
        }

        MenuStrip ms;
        ToolStripMenuItem tsmi;
        using (Form form = new Form {
            MainMenuStrip = (ms = new MenuStrip {
                Items = {
                    (tsmi = new ToolStripMenuItem("def"))
                }
            })
        })
        {
            form.Controls.Add(ms);
            tsmi.DropDownItems.Add("dummy");
            tsmi.DropDownOpening += delegate {
                tsmi.DropDownItems.Clear();
                tsmi.DropDownItems.Add(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            };
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was so easy and I thought there is no way in C#.